# Power series solution to Laguerre differential equation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, differential

The question is asking to find some power series $P(x)$ that satisfies the Laguerre differential equation:

$$xy''+(1-x)y'-y=0\text,$$

with initial condition $P(0) = 1$.

I am aware the solution to the differential equation is $P(x) = \exp(x)$ via WolframAlpha, so I thus know the power series. However, I must find a proof of this. The problem must be solvable without using DE solving techniques, since those have not been covered. What I have tried is plugging a general power series into the DE and simplifying by taking derivatives of it, but that did not seem to help.

I would prefer a hint over a full solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Please do not vandalize posted questions, including your own. Rolled back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n\\
xP''(x)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n-1)na_nx^{n-1}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n}\\
(1-x)P'(x)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_nx^{n}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_nx^{n}\\
a_n&=n(n+1)a_{n+1}+(n+1)a_{n+1}-na_n\quad(n\ge0)\\
a_{n+1}&=\frac{a_n}{n+1}\quad\quad(n\ge0)\\
P(0)&=1\rightarrow a_0=1\\
\therefore a_n&=\frac1{n!}\\
\end{align}
, which also means that $P(x)=e^x$.

Comment: It can start from $0, 1$, or $2$, because $n(n-1)=0$ for either $n=0$ or $n=1$. I just chose $1$ to make it look smoother for $n$ to $n+1$ transition.

Comment: $P(0)=1+0+0+0+\dots$, because $x^0=1$.

Comment: It's arguable but in this case $0^0=1$, because $a_0 x^0$ was just a different notation for $a_0$. Or, let's just say $P(x)=a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^n$.